# Syntax differences between Command Prompt and Terminal

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash, terminal

I am studying the differences between the Windows command prompt syntax and the Ubuntu Terminal syntax. I've been messing around with cd, cd(space backslash), cd(backslash), cd/, cd /, cd.., cd .., etc...
I'm kind of getting myself confused when I switch between the two command-lines. At first it seemed like there was not really a difference besides the forward slash being used in Linux and the backslash being used in Windows.

For example, in command prompt I can type

```
C:\>cd users
```

^(no backslash)

```
C:\>cd \users
```

^(backslash before users)

```
C:\>cd users\
```

^(backslash after users)

```
C:\>cd \users\
```

^(backslash before and after users)

Whereas in Linux:

[Doing the exact same input but with /home/meestermoo/Documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSL0C.png)

It seems like the only difference in syntax is that Linux is picky about placement of the slash. It can only be present before the command cd or not at all. If this is correct, is this syntax usually true for all commands involving a slash? Just trying to get my head around the syntax differences. Please correct me if I've got any wrong assumptions!

Thanks!

Comment: cmd and sh use similar syntax for basic navigation (cd, dir/ls, mkdir, del/rm, etc ), but once you get past those basics, they are quite different. sh is much more "full featured" and really compares better to windows powershell in terms of features and capabilities (though powershell uses a much more distinct syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cd \users works the same as cd users because you're at the root of the drive C:\

if you cd users and type cd username you'll get the same result as on linux.

Prepending a \ or / to a path specifies it as being absolute and defined from the drive root.

This works the same on both platforms.

so cd \users\blah on windows cd /home/fred/documents on linux

your cd \users example works because users exists in the root of C: it's not a syntactic difference between platforms.